# GET, then manipulate that info (while loop and if statements), then PUT

Tags: api

I feel like this is a simple enough thing to do and can't believe how hard of a time I'm having finding the example I need so alas, human help please! You failed me Google :)

FYI I've written a bit of code in my life (Java, C, ASM, PHP), new to APIs.

As the title lays bare, I want to retrieve info (tickets out of our ticketing system meeting certain conditions) via a GET request, loop through each ticket, and update each one (PUT) based on certain conditions.

If there's a tutorial you know of that covers that, please point me to it! If not, if you could please fill in some of these holes?

I wound up in Postman, is this an appropriate environment to accomplish such? Of course you can make individual API calls here but I got lost trying to string the aforementioned sequence together. Is it possible via "Create API?"  This makes it sound like I'm creating my own API server for other users to access data from.  If it is possible via "Create API," where's the dang run code button?!  If not Postman, what tool should I be using to write code in?  And again, if you have any code samples/videos closely resembling said scenario for that tool.

Thank you for any assistance you can offer.

Cheers,
Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to interact with your ticketing system: read existing tickets, and update them.  Correct?

To do this, your *TICKETING SYSTEM* must have an "[api](https://medium.com/@gabrymartinez/stupid-question-of-the-day-what-is-the-difference-between-web-api-and-rest-api-336ee747ce84)" (possibly - but not necessarily - a [REST](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/understanding-using-rest-api/) API).

If it does, you might be in luck.  But you need to learn the API first, possibly from product documentation.  If it doesn't, there's probably not much you can do except to interact with the system as a "normal user".

If it has an API, and if it's a relatively simple API (like REST), you can use the API manually (e.g. through POSTMAN), or you can use it programmatically (using Python, C#, Java or just about any programming language you feel comfortable with).

In summary, you need to:

1. Determine if your ticketing system provides any kind of web api
2. If so, get the API details
3. If at that point you want proceed, determine what programming language or framework you'd like to use.

Hopefully that gives you a bit of "direction".

Comment: Correct, reading existing tickets and updating them (GET then PUT).  Freshdesk def has an API - https://developers.freshdesk.com/api/ - and I'll code probably in whatever I find the sample in.

Can I do it in Postman?  Link to sample code/YouTube/tutorial showing how?

Comment: Ah - I use Freshdesk myself :)  But I've never used the API, nor tried to automate it.  I just manually use the standard web UI :)  The FD examples are all in [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/).  Regarding Postman, these articles might be helpful: https://blog.postman.com/curl-and-postman-work-wonderfully-together/ or https://www.taniarascia.com/making-api-requests-postman-curl/.  I'd also consider trying a programming language (Java, C#, Python - whatever). Please "upvote" and/or "accept" if you wish.